# How to create a type that can be used as an index

Tags: typescript

In my app I have a few kinds of IDs (Customer Id, Item Id, Transfer Id, etc.). I don't want to mix them, so I'm trying to create a specific type for each one of them.

```js
class CustomerId extends String {
  protected __nominal = true;
};
```

and later:

```js
const customers: {[customerId: CustomerId]: Customer} = {};
```

That of course does not work, typescript says that only a string or a number can be used as index.
Is there any other way of achieving that?

Comment: Since an object can't have a type as a key, that'll be hard. You can use a Map though

Comment: There's probably a better way of achieving this, perhaps with `{[cusomerID in CustomerIDs]: Customer} = {}`. But More details on your end goal will be necessary to suggest anything relevant.